# Save a date and time in a specific format in a variable | linux debian sh script

Tags: linux, sh

I'm trying to save 2 dates in 2 variables but they have a specific format (*since files are names like that*).

They are named as the following

```
2014-10-27_08.01.01
2014-10-27_18.00.01
```

So i have it in my script as

`startdate=$(date -d -u +"2014-10-27_08.01.01")`

`enddate=$(date -d -u +"2014-10-27_18.00.01")`

But whenever i run the sh script i get the invalid date error.
I know it can probably not read it but i can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date` doesn't understand the underscore `_` and the dots `.` in the string. You need to convert it to something that works, for example

```
startdate=$(echo "2014-10-27_08.01.01"|sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/\./:/g')
enddate=$(echo "2014-10-27_18.00.01"|sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/\./:/g')
```

This will result:

```
~]# date -u -d "$startdate"
 Mon Oct 27 08:01:01 UTC 2014
```

Here is a script that uses a function to reformat the string in the file name

```
 #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                 

 inputDateFmt()
 {
    sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/\./:/g' <<< "$1"
 }
 startdate=$(date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt "2014-10-27_08.01.01")")
 enddate=$(date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt "2014-10-27_18.00.01")")
 echo $startdate
 echo $enddate
```

Results in:

```
~]# ./datefmt.bash
Mon Oct 27 08:01:01 UTC 2014
Mon Oct 27 18:00:01 UTC 2014
```

Comment: Hello thank you for responding but i will explain a bit more what i need this for. So basically i need to check a txt file for missing dates, and the dates are formatted like i mentioned.